# Having + past participle or Having been + past participl

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, active-vs-passive

Please help me get to know these. I am not able to differentiate the usage between these two **having + past participle** and **having been + past participle**

For instance(just to give a clearer vision of what my question is):

> 1. After having your arm broken, you should go to a doctor.
> 2. After having your arm been broken, you should go to a doctor.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these works in the meaning you intend, unfortunately.

(2) is totally ungrammatical, so forget it for now.

(1) would **usually** be interpreted as "after you have intentionally caused somebody to break your arm, you should go to a doctor". Compare:

- I'm having my car fixed
- I'm having my hair dyed
- After having his enemies shot, Prince Bressingham rode on to London

The sentence you want is:

- After having broken your arm, you should go to a doctor.

However, because this is general advice, there is no need to use *having* + PP. You can just say

- After breaking your arm, you should go to a doctor.

Or even more naturally:

- If you break your arm, you should go to the doctor.

So to answer your question, let's look at an example where your two constructions of interest could be used naturally:

- After having shot his enemies, Prince Grimblethreeb travelled to Huntingdon
- After having been shot by his enemies, Prince Thrumblestrump fled to Shitterton

Hopefully this makes clear that the distinction is simple one of **active vs. passive**---nothing more complicated than that. Just pay attention to the word order---nothing comes between *having* and the PP, or between *having been* and the PP!

(Later, you can add certain adverbials between them, but it's best to ignore this while you are learning to use them, especially since some authorities would proscribe such usage: *After having been mercilessly shot...*)

And why use the construction at all, given what we said about *after breaking your arm, you should go to a doctor*? Well, as you can see, one use of the construction is to describe something that had already been done in the past when some subsequent event occurred. You might think of it as an alternative to a typical pluperfect + past simple sentence like:

- After he had shot his enemies, Prince G travelled to H.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] [*After having your arm broken*], *you should go to a doctor.*
>
> [2] [*After having your arm been broken*], *you should go to a doctor.*

[1] is grammatically fine: it's the passive equivalent of "After breaking your arm". Your example contains what's known as a 'bare passive'; it's called this because it lacks the "be" and "get" markers that normally occur in passive clauses.

[2] is ungrammatical since it is not possible to insert another past participle ("been") in the passive verb phrase "broken".